# Help with proof by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

The author generates a Tower of Hanoi and looks at the sequence:

$$1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63,...$$

He guesses the recurrence relation from the first few terms:

$$H_{n} = 2^{n} - 1$$

Now he wants to prove it using proof by induction:

> **Base case**: For $n = 1$, it's true.
>
> **Induction case**: Assume for induction that $H_{n - 1} = 2^{n - 1} - 1$, then
>
> $$\begin{align*} H_{n} & = 2H_{n - 1} + 1 \\
> & = 2(2^{n - 1} - 1) + 1 \\
> & = 2^n - 1\end{align*}
> $$

I don't understand the above equation. First he says that $H_{n} = 2^{n} - 1$ and then he changes it to $H_{n} = 2H_{n - 1} + 1$ - I don't get the logic in that.

Comment: The first time it was mentioned was a "guess", he wanted to prove that guess was right by using induction, so he showed it was true for a base case. Then showed that by assuming it holds true for n-1 implies it holds for n.

Comment: The relation $H_n=2H_{n-1}+1$ likely comes from how you solve the game.

Comment: $2^n-1$ describes the $n$th term (as initially hypothesised), whereas $2H_{n-1}+1$ describes how to get from one term to the next.

Comment: Look at the table on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TowerofHanoi.html) - notice the largest piece comes in the middle of the sequence. The recurrence relation is a consequence of this symmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recurrence relation is not 
$$
H_{n}=2^{n}-1
$$

but rather 
$$
H_{n}=2H_{n-1}+1
$$

(this comes from the Hanoi problem)

We now guess that the solution to the recurrence is 
$$
H_{n}=2^{n}-1
$$

and show that this is true using induction.

There is the base case that should be clear, our hypothesis would
be $H_{n-1}=2^{n-1}-1$ and we would use it to prove 
$$
H_{n}=2^{n}-1
$$

By using the recurrence relation 
$$
H_{n}=2H_{n-1}+1
$$

and now use the induction hypothesis and set $H_{n-1}=2^{n-1}-1$
and we get 
$$
H_{n}=2(2^{n-1}-1)+1=2^{n}-2+1=2^{n}-1
$$

which is what we wanted to prove

Comment: The author wrote code that generated the Hanoi Tower and he said "Now we can see that we have the recurrence relation $H_n = 2H_{n-1} + 1$". How can we see that??

Comment: @David - Try pasting the code to http://lpaste.net/ its hard to read it from your comment

Comment: http://lpaste.net/110522

Comment: @David - We denote the total number of transfers we have to make to solve the problem with $n$ disks $with $H_n$. From this code you see that to solve the problem with $n$ disk requires you to solve the problem with $n-1$ disks twice - this is the call to hanoi_move(n-1, from, other, to) and to   hanoi_move(n-1, other, to, from) - Each of them takes, by definition, $H_{n-1}$ transfers, we also need to make one more transfer - which is the line - move one disk from the "from" peg to the "to" peg

Comment: Its hard to read - but I'm referring to $2$ recursive calls to Hanoi plus the last call to move one disk

Comment: I think you forgot to insert one `$` lol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if sometimes you can't guess the closed form (i.e the sequence of numbers are too large and complex). What could you do then?

Comment: @David - There are many ways to solve recursion formulas . One way is with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 1):

I think it stems from the fact that the general algorithm to solve a Tower of Hanoi with $n$ rings is to solve one with $n-1$, to move the base, and then to resolve the $n-1$ tower. For more details: http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/recursion/examples/section6.rhtml or just google around. Since $n-1$ Tower of Hanoi requires $H_{n-1}$ moves, $H_n$ must require $H_{n-1}$ to initially move the $n-1$ rings, plus $1$ move to to move the base ring, and then a further $H_{n-1}$ to move the $n-1$ rings back, for a total of $H_{n-1} + 1 + H_{n-1}=2H_{n-1}+1$